# The meaning of ‘repair’

Tags: meaning

> Let us raise a standard to which the wise and honest can repair

What is the meaning of repair in this context??

Comment: *Repair* has the meaning of *go*, *rally*, *return*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is the intransitive sense (OED v1) of the verb *repair* meaning "return to" or "go to". Its various intransitive senses are listed in the OED as below. Both it and the transitive sense (OED v2) of "making good something which is damaged" are of Norman French origin - "reparer"**

The OED provides examples in English from circa 1325 roughly the same time as the alternative sense.

The one which comes closest to yours in the below senses, is I believe sense 4 - the only one for which I provide the OED examples.

> Forms:  ME repeire, ME repeyer, ME repeyre, ME–16 repaire, ME–16
>   repare, ME–16 repayer, ME–16 repayr, ME–16 repayre, ME– repair; Sc.
>   pre-17 rapare, pre-17 repaer, pre-17 repaire, pre-17 repar, pre-17
>   repare, pre-17 repayr, pre-17 repayre, pre-17 repear, pre-17 reper,
>   pre-17 17– repair. (Show Less) Frequency (in current use):  Origin: A
>   borrowing from French. Etymons: French repeirer, repairier. Etymology:
>   < Anglo-Norman repeirer, reparier, repairir, etc., Anglo-Norman and
>   Old French, Middle French repairier, Anglo-Norman and Middle French
>   repairer, reparer, Middle French reperer (French †repairer ) to
>   return, go back, to go home, to head for, to go, to arrive, (of
>   memory, strength, etc.) to return (also reflexive; end of the 11th
>   cent.; also c1100 as repadrer ), to dwell, reside, stay, to frequent
>   (12th cent.) < post-classical Latin repatriare to return to one's
>   country (see repatriate v.). Compare post-classical Latin repariare to
>   resort (1275 in a British source), Old Occitan repairar.(Show Less)
>    1. intr   a. To return to or from a specified place or person; to come back again. Usually with from, to, etc.
>
> †b. Without origin or destination specified: to return, come back.
>   Also with again. Obs.
>
> 2. a. intr. To go, proceed, set out, make one's way. Also: to arrive. Frequently with from, to, (arch.) unto, etc. Also in extended use.
>
>    b. trans. (refl.). = sense 2a. Now arch.
> 3. a. intr. To go habitually or frequently to a place or (occasionally) a person. Chiefly with to, †unto.
>
> †b. intr. To be present or assembled, habitually or temporarily; to
>   present oneself; to stay, dwell, reside. Obs.
>
> †c. trans. (refl.) in same sense. Obs.
>
> 4. intr. To resort; to have recourse to a person or thing for aid, guidance, etc. Now arch.In later use merging with sense 2a.
>
> c1475   Wisdom (Folg.) (1969) 71   O worthy spowse and soueren
>   father..to yowr loue wo dothe repeyer.
>
> 1539   T. Elyot Bankette of Sapience f. 44   Hym, whose howse is..open
>   to all menne, where euery manne, as it were in tempestes and stormes,
>   may repayre for theyr succours.
>
> 1580   Sir P. Sidney tr. Psalmes David ix. v   Thither the world for
>   justice shall repaire.
>
> 1655   T. Fuller Church-hist. Brit. ii. 150   If any desire farther
>   Information herein, let him repair to the worthy Work,
>   which..the..Arch-bishop of Armagh, hath written.
>
> 1707   E. Ward Wooden World Dissected 62   Sometimes his
>   Captain..repairs to him for a Refitment.
>
> 1722   W. Wollaston Relig. of Nature vii. 145   No shops to repair to
>   for tools.
>
> 1817   Panoplist Nov. 493   Flee to him for safety... Sensible that
>   you are justly condemned, may you repair to Christ as guilty, and
>   ruined, and helpless.
>
> 1968   K. A. Menninger Crime of Punishm. x. 254   Illness..is best
>   defined as a state of impaired functioning of such a nature that the
>   public expects the sufferer to repair to the physician for help.
>
> 1992   New Yorker 3 Feb. 52/2   At a luncheon meeting..he repaired to
>   the Bible for a spirited apologia for the tradition of liberalism.
>
> 5,   a. To convey, deliver. Obs. rare.    b. With back. To recover,
>   reclaim. Obs. rare.